# What is the meaning of this JetBrains/PyCharm/WebStorm shortcut combination?

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Can anyone explain to me how to use this shortcut combination on a mac?

[image]

Comment: It's a 2-step shortcut: For first one:  1) `Command/Meta + *` 2) and then `1` ... `5` (**note** -- the `*` is the one located on NumPad`); For second one: `Alt + Command/Meta + *` and then `1` ... `5`

Comment: This is how it looks when checking Mac OS keymap on Windows PC: https://postimg.org/image/7zc6142n1/ -- should be more readable; For actual key icons: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mac+os+keyboard+icons&tbm=isch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>⌘</kbd> is the Command key, <kbd>⌨ *</kbd> ("keyboard asterisk") refers to the <kbd>*</kbd> key *on the numeric key pad* (<kbd>Shift + 8</kbd> on a US keyboard won't do). The whole combination reads as:

> Command key + multiplication key on the numpad, (lift your fingers) then a number between 1 and 5

For completeness, <kbd>⌥</kbd> is the option/alt key.